# Organizing code in Django views

Tags: python, django, django-views, dry

I have the following code in my `index view` in the `views.py`:

```
   def index(request):  
        # Count all active polls for posting on the index page.
        all_active_polls = Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                                               is_active=True
                                              ).order_by('-pub_date')
        num_of_active_polls = len(all_active_polls)
        # Count all inactive polls for posting on the index page.
        all_inactive_polls = Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                                                 is_active=False
                                                ).order_by('-pub_date')
        num_of_inactive_polls = len(all_inactive_polls)
        # Make the list of the last 5 published polls.
        latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.annotate(num_choices=Count('choice')) \
               .filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                       is_active=True,
                       num_choices__gte=2) \
               .order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {
            'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
            'num_of_active_polls': num_of_active_polls,
            'num_of_inactive_polls': num_of_inactive_polls
            })
```

On the index page I want to have a list of my last 5 (or more, don't matter) polls.
And after that I want to have two links: `View all active polls(number of polls)` and `View all closed polls(number of polls)`. So I need to count it in the `index` view code. *But*, I'm not sure it's the best place to put this code (that counts number of active and inactive polls).

And also maybe I will need this numbers in some other views, so I will copy this code to this views? I think it hurts **DRY** and Django focuses on adhering to the DRY principle.

So how can I reorganize this code to make it more logical and not to hurt the *DRY* principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/) to make it more DRY, always follow the principle - fat model, thin view.
Here's one way of doing this:

models.py

```
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, active=True):
        return super(ActiveManager, self).\
            get_query_set().filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), is_active=active)\
                           .order_by('-pub_date')

class InctiveManager(InctiveManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(InctiveManager, self).get_query_set(is_active=False)

class LatestManager(InctiveManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LatestManager, self).get_query_set(is_active=True)\
                                         .filter(num_choices__gte=2)\
                                         .annotate(num_choices=Count('choice'))

class Poll(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    active = ActiveManager()
    inctive = InctiveManager()
    latest = LatestManager()
```

views.py

```
all_active_polls = Poll.active.all()
num_of_active_polls = len(all_active_polls)

all_inactive_polls = Poll.inactive.all()
num_of_inactive_polls = len(all_inactive_polls)

latest_poll_list = Poll.latest.all()[:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I must ask, is there a reason you are not using [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)?

You could have one [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) with `n` last polls where you could define that number in get_queryset method
Another ListView with different queryset and that view could use the same template if you please or different one.
And another ListView for all closed polls.

If you have a lot of custom code that you want to be used in all views just write a mixin that all your other class based views will inherit.